# Android RotationAnimation Complete

Tags: android, animation, translation

I am trying to use the RotationAnimation to move an ImageButton.  I have extended ImageButton to override onAnimationEnd to avoid the screen flicker at the end of the animation, and would like to update the position of the actual button [since the animation is just a superficial move].  How can I determine the exact coordinates of the button at the end of the animation?  Attached is some of my code..

```
public class HomeNavigationButton extends ImageButton {
public HomeNavigationButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
public HomeNavigationButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public HomeNavigationButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
protected void onAnimationEnd() {
    super.onAnimationEnd();
    int l = ?
    int t = ?
    int r = ?
    int b = ?
    this.layout(l,t,r,b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the button animation?  I would go out on a limb and guess you can't.  Animations are interesting.  They're not "real".  Think of them as a mirage.  Try this.  Rotate the image VERY slowly.  If the image is a rectangle, when the image is about 45 degrees, click where the image used to be, but is no long.  You'll actually register a click, because the image isn't *actually* being rotate in real coordinates.

I would consider actually animating the button like a game sprite, or do some trial and error with the animation and set values manually.  If you do the second one, make sure you dynamically convert to DIP coordinates rather than raw ints.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I have tried to set them manually, but can't get exact enough to avoid the button "jumping" a pixel or two.  Very frustrating!